# Pass GET parameters during app installation

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

When user install the application, the page is redirected without initially GET parameters.

For example:

1. user open app with the link: http://apps.facebook.com/[app]/?request_ids=123&fb_source=wall
2. this app is not installed, so the Facebook redirect to page: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[app]redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/[app]/?scope=user_about_me,email&response_type=code
3. after user confirms necessary permissions, he is redirected to page: https://apps.facebook.com/[app]/?code=[authorization code]

In final url the initial GET parameters are missed, so I can't detect from which URL the user come to my application.

I use the following C# code to generate login url:

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.client_id = _configuration.AppId;
parameters.redirect_uri = _configuration.CanvasUrl;
parameters.scope = String.Join(",", accessScope);
parameters.response_type = "code";
return _facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```

I can't use GET parameters in parameters.redirect_uri value (Facebook error - URL is incorrect).

Please advice how can I use initial GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same `redirect_uri` parameter in both steps of the authentication -

Although you haven't included enough information there, i suspect the auth dialog is loading OK, users are accepting it, but your attempt to exchange the `code` for an `access_token` is failing because you aren't using the same redirect_uri (*with* the parameters)